# App Works from Xcode, Crashes when uploaded to Apple and exported as Developer Release

Tags: swift, xcode, crash, submit, macos-mojave

I'm stumped on this one. I've uploaded my app multiple times to Apple recently and each time it's being rejected due to a crash on Mojave 10.14.6. When running from Xcode 10.2.1 the app behaves properly. But, if exported to a developer release, or uploaded to apple for review it 'crashes' on launch. However, code that sets the app up copying certain data to the app container works meaning the app is launching and executing code. But the OS is closing it for some reason. The 'update' I'm testing against now is a direct copy of the code uploaded on the current store build that has been 100% crash free for months. I pulled the code from the release tag so it's identical. But now for some reason on this OS version it will crash. I've also revoked my certs, created new ones and created new provisioning profiles with no luck.

Any help identifying the issue would be awesome! I've attached the crash log supplied by apple below.

Also, is there a way to launch a Mac app with the scheme set to release on the mac? Any time I try this I get the error "Message from debugger: Error 1"

Thank you!

```
Date/Time:             2019-08-27 16:53:58.186 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G87)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        ---

Sleep/Wake UUID:       ---

Time Awake Since Boot: 29000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       10000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [4905]

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.company.app 0x0000000101c2f800 0x101beb000 + 280576
1   com.company.app 0x0000000101c3d9cf 0x101beb000 + 338383
2   com.company.app 0x0000000101c44b9b 0x101beb000 + 367515
3   com.company.app 0x0000000101c3bca3 0x101beb000 + 330915
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3c5238bc -[NSClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 602
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff41153417 _decodeObjectBinary + 2519
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff4115291e _decodeObject + 246
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff4115281a -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:] + 205
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3c4d91c0 -[NSNibConnector initWithCoder:] + 96
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3c4d9048 -[NSNibOutletConnector initWithCoder:] + 76
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff41153417 _decodeObjectBinary + 2519
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff41154d76 -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1682
12  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff41154327 -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 198
13  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff41153417 _decodeObjectBinary + 2519
14  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff4115291e _decodeObject + 246
15  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff4115281a -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:] + 205
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3c4d7c88 -[NSIBObjectData initWithCoder:] + 201
17  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff41153417 _decodeObjectBinary + 2519
18  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff4115291e _decodeObject + 246
19  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff4115281a -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:] + 205
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3c66af37 -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:] + 535
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3c66ac23 -[NSNib _instantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 136
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3cd395df -[NSStoryboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:] + 236
23  com.company.app 0x0000000101c1e440 0x101beb000 + 209984
24  com.company.app 0x0000000101c1e83e 0x101beb000 + 211006
25  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3ef4eb96 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
26  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3ef4eb10 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 63
27  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3ef4ea7a _CFXRegistrationPost + 404
28  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3ef56f28 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 87
29  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3eebf8b4 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1642
30  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3eebec67 _CFXNotificationPost + 732
31  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff41144f5b -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3c4e8fc4 -[NSApplication _postDidFinishNotification] + 312
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3c4e8917 -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification] + 208
34  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3c4e6a6b -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 552
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3c4e66bb -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 688
36  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff4118eb3c -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 286
37  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff4118e9b9 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 102
38  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff40110397 aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 1815
39  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff4010fc29 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) + 41
40  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff4010fb01 aeProcessAppleEvent + 414
41  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff3e1538b7 AEProcessAppleEvent + 54
42  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3c4e2abd _DPSNextEvent + 1935
43  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3c4e148b -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1361
44  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3c4db5a8 -[NSApplication run] + 699
45  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3c4caae8 NSApplicationMain + 777
46  com.company.app 0x0000000101bee919 0x101beb000 + 14617
47  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6ae3d3d5 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6b0303f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6b0303f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6b0303f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6b0303f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6b0303f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6b0303f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fffa15fb628  rcx: 0x0000000100001d80  rdx: 0x0040000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000600001a5c430  rsi: 0x00007fff3d0658d9  rbp: 0x00007ffeee012450  rsp: 0x00007ffeee0123c0
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0xffffffff00000000  r10: 0x00007ffeee014ca0  r11: 0x00007fff6a8a1a60
  r12: 0x0000600001a5c430  r13: 0x00007ffeee0123d0  r14: 0x0000600003038b00  r15: 0x00007fff6a857750
  rip: 0x0000000101c2f800  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000600000e42000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     6


Binary Images:
       0x101beb000 -        0x101cf2ff7 +com.company.app (3.1.7 - 60) <393830A3-E2A7-361D-B48C-06FB10B80E5A> /Applications/AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName
       0x101d57000 -        0x101d64fff +org.cocoapods.MASShortcut (2.3.6 - 1) <23790BC4-C77D-39B7-AD30-3D49E0E5388B> /Applications/AppName.app/Contents/Frameworks/MASShortcut.framework/Versions/A/MASShortcut
       0x107333000 -        0x107336047  libobjc-trampolines.dylib (756.2) <5795A048-3940-3801-90CE-33D1B1AF81F4> /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
       0x10b0a0000 -        0x10b10a6ef  dyld (655.1.1) <D3E77331-ACE5-349D-A7CC-433D626D4A5B> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff33613000 -     0x7fff3396cfff  com.apple.RawCamera.bundle (8.15.0 - 1031.4.4) <AB6E8A8F-0BFE-37EE-A135-44ABA4FCB559> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/Contents/MacOS/RawCamera
    0x7fff3396f000 -     0x7fff33a7bfff  com.apple.AMDMTLBronzeDriver (2.11.20 - 2.1.1) <1D8E8E3B-88F4-35B1-8E83-AE74B558C26C> /System/Library/Extensions/AMDMTLBronzeDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AMDMTLBronzeDriver
    0x7fff3aeea000 -     0x7fff3b0c6ffb  com.apple.avfoundation (2.0 - 1550.4) <5854207B-6106-3DA4-80B6-36C42D042F26> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AVFoundation
    0x7fff3b0c7000 -     0x7fff3b18cfff  com.apple.audio.AVFAudio (1.0 - ???) <D454A339-2FC6-3EF6-992F-D676046612DB> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AVFAudio.framework/Versions/A/AVFAudio
    0x7fff3b294000 -     0x7fff3b294fff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.11 - Accelerate 1.11) <762942CB-CFC9-3A0C-9645-A56523A06426> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff3b295000 -     0x7fff3b2abff7  libCGInterfaces.dylib (506.22) <1B6C92D9-F4B8-37BA-9635-94C4A56098CE> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCGInterfaces.dylib
    0x7fff3b2ac000 -     0x7fff3b945fef  com.apple.vImage (8.1 - ???) <53FA3611-894E-3158-A654-FBD2F70998FE> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff3b946000 -     0x7fff3bbbfff3  libBLAS.dylib (1243.200.4) <417CA0FC-B6CB-3FB3-ACBC-8914E3F62D20> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff3bbc0000 -     0x7fff3bc32ffb  libBNNS.dylib (38.250.1) <538D12A2-9B9D-3E22-9896-F90F6E69C06E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBNNS.dylib
    0x7fff3bc33000 -     0x7fff3bfdcff3  libLAPACK.dylib (1243.200.4) <92175DF4-863A-3780-909A-A3E5C410F2E9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff3bfdd000 -     0x7fff3bff2feb  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1243.200.4) <CB671EE6-DEA1-391C-9B2B-AA09A46B4D7A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x7fff3bff3000 -     0x7fff3bff8ff3  libQuadrature.dylib (3.200.2) <1BAE7E22-2862-379F-B334-A3756067730F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libQuadrature.dylib
    0x7fff3bff9000 -     0x7fff3c075ff3  libSparse.dylib (79.200.5) <E78B33D3-672A-3C53-B512-D3DDB2E9AC8D> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparse.dylib
    0x7fff3c076000 -     0x7fff3c089fe3  libSparseBLAS.dylib (1243.200.4) <E9243341-DB77-37C1-97C5-3DFA00DD70FA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparseBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff3c08a000 -     0x7fff3c271ff7  libvDSP.dylib (671.250.4) <7B110627-A9C1-3FB7-A077-0C7741BA25D8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff3c272000 -     0x7fff3c325ff7  libvMisc.dylib (671.250.4) <D5BA4812-BFFC-3CD0-B382-905CD8555DA6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff3c326000 -     0x7fff3c326fff  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.11 - vecLib 3.11) <74288115-EF61-30B6-843F-0593B31D4929> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff3c4c8000 -     0x7fff3d27dffb  com.apple.AppKit (6.9 - 1671.60.107) <DA722801-0527-3265-ADAE-BB2966649C7C> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff3d2cf000 -     0x7fff3d2cffff  com.apple.ApplicationServices (50.1 - 50.1) <84097DEB-E2FC-3901-8DD7-A670EA2274E0> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fff3d2d0000 -     0x7fff3d33bfff  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS (377 - 453.11.2.2) <A258DA73-114B-3102-A056-4AAAD3CEB9DD> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fff3d3d4000 -     0x7fff3d4ebfff  libFontParser.dylib (228.6.2.3) <3602D55B-3B9E-3B3A-A814-08C1244A8AE4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
    0x7fff3d4ec000 -     0x7fff3d52efff  libFontRegistry.dylib (228.12.2.3) <2A56347B-2809-3407-A8B4-2AB88E484062> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
    0x7fff3d588000 -     0x7fff3d5bafff  libTrueTypeScaler.dylib (228.6.2.3) <7E4C5D9C-51AF-3EC1-8FA5-11CD4BEE477A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTrueTypeScaler.dylib
    0x7fff3d61f000 -     0x7fff3d623ff3  com.apple.ColorSyncLegacy (4.13.0 - 1) <C0D9E23C-ABA0-39DE-A4EB-5A41C5499056> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSyncLegacy.framework/Versions/A/ColorSyncLegacy
    0x7fff3d6be000 -     0x7fff3d710ff7  com.apple.HIServices (1.22 - 628) <2BE461FF-80B9-30D3-A574-AED5724B1C1B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff3d711000 -     0x7fff3d720fff  com.apple.LangAnalysis (1.7.0 - 1.7.0) <F5617A2A-FEA6-3832-B5BA-C2111B98786F> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fff3d721000 -     0x7fff3d76aff7  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore (14.2 - 503.8) <57C2FE32-0E74-3079-B626-C2D52F2D2717> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff3d76b000 -     0x7fff3d7a4ff7  com.apple.QD (3.12 - 407.2) <28C7D39F-59C9-3314-BECC-67045487229C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
    0x7fff3d7a5000 -     0x7fff3d7b1fff  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework (8.1.3 - 8.1.3) <5E7B9BD4-122B-3012-A044-3259C97E7509> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff3d7b2000 -     0x7fff3da29ff7  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox (1.14 - 1.14) <04F482F1-E1C1-3955-8A6C-8AA152AA06F3> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
    0x7fff3da2b000 -     0x7fff3da2bfff  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit (1.14 - 1.14) <ABC54269-002D-310D-9654-46CF960F863E> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
    0x7fff3dd84000 -     0x7fff3e125fff  com.apple.CFNetwork (978.0.7 - 978.0.7) <B2133D0D-1399-3F17-80F0-313E3A241C89> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff3e13a000 -     0x7fff3e13afff  com.apple.Carbon (158 - 158) <56AD06AA-7BB4-3F0B-AEF7-9768D0BC1C98> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
    0x7fff3e13b000 -     0x7fff3e13effb  com.apple.CommonPanels (1.2.6 - 98) <1CD6D56D-8EC7-3528-8CBC-FC69533519B5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
    0x7fff3e13f000 -     0x7fff3e436fff  com.apple.HIToolbox (2.1.1 - 918.7) <13F69D4C-D19F-3E09-9231-1978D783A556> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
    0x7fff3e437000 -     0x7fff3e43aff3  com.apple.help (1.3.8 - 66) <A08517EB-8958-36C9-AEE0-1A8FEEACBE3F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
    0x7fff3e43b000 -     0x7fff3e440ff7  com.apple.ImageCapture (9.0 - 1534.2) <DB063E87-ED8F-3E4E-A7E2-A6B45FA73EF7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
    0x7fff3e441000 -     0x7fff3e4d6ff3  com.apple.ink.framework (10.9 - 225) <7C7E9483-2E91-3DD3-B1E0-C238F42CA0DD> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
    0x7fff3e4d7000 -     0x7fff3e4efff7  com.apple.openscripting (1.7 - 179.1) <9B8C1ECC-5864-3E21-9149-863E884EA25C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OpenScripting.framework/Versions/A/OpenScripting
    0x7fff3e50f000 -     0x7fff3e510ff7  com.apple.print.framework.Print (14.2 - 267.4) <A7A9D2A0-D4E0-35EF-A0F7-50521F707C33> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Print.framework/Versions/A/Print
    0x7fff3e511000 -     0x7fff3e513ff7  com.apple.securityhi (9.0 - 55006) <05717F77-7A7B-37E6-AB3E-03F063E9095B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
    0x7fff3e514000 -     0x7fff3e51aff7  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework (6.0.3 - 6.0.3) <3CC050FB-EBCB-3087-8EA5-F378C8F99217> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
    0x7fff3e63c000 -     0x7fff3e63cfff  com.apple.Cocoa (6.11 - 23) <A9778F0D-0DBC-3978-B92D-5E87FE1CB75D> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fff3e64a000 -     0x7fff3e799ff7  com.apple.ColorSync (4.13.0 - 3345.6) <31648BB6-7239-3D0E-81B1-BCF51FEF557F> /System/Library/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff3e925000 -     0x7fff3e9abfff  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio (4.3.0 - 4.3.0) <1E8E64E6-0E58-375A-97F7-07CB4EE181AC> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
    0x7fff3ea0f000 -     0x7fff3ea39ffb  com.apple.CoreBluetooth (1.0 - 1) <A73F1709-DD18-3052-9F22-C0015278834B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/CoreBluetooth
    0x7fff3ea3a000 -     0x7fff3edbffef  com.apple.CoreData (120 - 866.6) <132CB39B-8D58-30FA-B8AD-49BFFF34B293> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
    0x7fff3edc0000 -     0x7fff3eeb0ff7  com.apple.CoreDisplay (101.3 - 110.18) <0EB2A997-FCAD-3D17-B140-9829961E5327> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreDisplay.framework/Versions/A/CoreDisplay
    0x7fff3eeb1000 -     0x7fff3f2f5fe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1575.17) <EE7948FC-FDA8-3F95-A1E0-69FAED5D81AA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff3f2f7000 -     0x7fff3f986fff  com.apple.CoreGraphics (2.0 - 1265.9) <BC95B558-EF77-3A57-A0BC-11606C778991> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fff3f988000 -     0x7fff3fca8fff  com.apple.CoreImage (14.4.0 - 750.0.140) <11026E39-D2FF-3CF6-8ACE-7BA293F9853E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Versions/A/CoreImage
    0x7fff3fd7b000 -     0x7fff3ffa4fff  com.apple.CoreML (1.0 - 1) <9EC1FED2-BA47-307B-A326-43C4D05166E7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreML.framework/Versions/A/CoreML
    0x7fff3ffa5000 -     0x7fff400a9fff  com.apple.CoreMedia (1.0 - 2290.13) <A739B93D-23C2-3A34-8D61-6AC924B9634F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/Versions/A/CoreMedia
    0x7fff400aa000 -     0x7fff40105fff  com.apple.CoreMediaIO (900.0 - 5050.1) <5F35E97B-2610-3744-94B6-062B0C27A6FD> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMediaIO.framework/Versions/A/CoreMediaIO
    0x7fff40106000 -     0x7fff40106fff  com.apple.CoreServices (946 - 946) <455AB7C9-ECB1-3B5C-8D07-AC68810A90B1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff40107000 -     0x7fff40183ff7  com.apple.AE (773 - 773) <55AE7C9E-27C3-30E9-A047-3B92A6FD53B4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff40184000 -     0x7fff4045bfff  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1178.33 - 1178.33) <CB87F0C7-2CD6-3983-8E32-B6A2EC925352> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff4045c000 -     0x7fff404a4ff7  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 284.16.4) <746EB200-DC51-30AE-9CBC-608A7B4CC8DA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff404a5000 -     0x7fff404adffb  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1239.200.12 - 1239.200.12) <8406D379-8D33-3611-861B-7ABD26DB50D2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
    0x7fff404ae000 -     0x7fff4065fff7  com.apple.LaunchServices (946 - 946) <A0C91634-9410-38E8-BC11-7A5A369E6BA5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff40660000 -     0x7fff406feff7  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 1191.57) <BFFAED00-2560-318A-BB8F-4E7E5123EC61> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff406ff000 -     0x7fff40749ff7  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (946 - 946) <20C4EEF8-D5AC-39A0-9B4A-78F88E3EFBCC> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff4074a000 -     0x7fff407b1ff7  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.0 - 1.4.0) <DA08AA6F-A6F1-36C0-87F4-E26294E51A3A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff407b2000 -     0x7fff407d3ff3  com.apple.coreservices.SharedFileList (71.28 - 71.28) <487A8464-729E-305A-B5D1-E3FE8EB9CFC5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SharedFileList.framework/Versions/A/SharedFileList
    0x7fff40ade000 -     0x7fff40c40ff3  com.apple.CoreText (352.0 - 584.26.3.2) <59919B0C-CBD5-3877-8D6F-D6048F1E5F42> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    0x7fff40c41000 -     0x7fff40c81ff3  com.apple.CoreVideo (1.8 - 281.4) <10CF8E52-07E3-382B-8091-2CEEEFFA69B4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
    0x7fff40c82000 -     0x7fff40d11fff  com.apple.framework.CoreWLAN (13.0 - 1375.2) <BF4B29F7-FBC8-3299-98E8-C3F8C04B7C92> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreWLAN.framework/Versions/A/CoreWLAN
    0x7fff40e94000 -     0x7fff40f42fff  com.apple.DiscRecording (9.0.3 - 9030.4.5) <D7A28B57-C025-3D44-BB17-82243B7B91BC> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiscRecording.framework/Versions/A/DiscRecording
    0x7fff40f68000 -     0x7fff40f6dffb  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.7 - 2.7) <F481F2C0-884E-3265-8111-ABBEC93F0920> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff41133000 -     0x7fff414e0fff  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1575.17) <20150BA3-74D6-3991-AD22-52735FAD0E24> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff4154f000 -     0x7fff4157effb  com.apple.GSS (4.0 - 2.0) <E2B90D08-3857-3155-9FCC-07D778988EC9> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/GSS
    0x7fff4167e000 -     0x7fff41788fff  com.apple.Bluetooth (6.0.14 - 6.0.14d3) <C2D1A774-2390-363D-8215-BF51FFCB6CCA> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/IOBluetooth
    0x7fff417eb000 -     0x7fff4187afff  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1483.260.4) <8A90F547-86EF-3DFB-92FE-0E2C0376DD84> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff4187c000 -     0x7fff4188bffb  com.apple.IOSurface (255.6.1 - 255.6.1) <85F85EBB-EA59-3A8B-B3EB-7C20F3CC77AE> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
    0x7fff4188c000 -     0x7fff418deff3  com.apple.ImageCaptureCore (1.0 - 1534.2) <27942C51-8108-3ED9-B37E-7C365A31EC2D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageCaptureCore.framework/Versions/A/ImageCaptureCore
    0x7fff418df000 -     0x7fff41a6afef  com.apple.ImageIO.framework (3.3.0 - 1850.2) <75E46A31-D87D-35CE-86A4-96A50971FDB2> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fff41a6b000 -     0x7fff41a6fffb  libGIF.dylib (1850.2) <4774EBDF-583B-3DDD-A0E1-9F427CB6A074> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
    0x7fff41a70000 -     0x7fff41b4cfef  libJP2.dylib (1850.2) <697BB77F-A682-339F-8659-35432962432D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJP2.dylib
    0x7fff41b4d000 -     0x7fff41b72feb  libJPEG.dylib (1850.2) <171A8AC4-AADA-376F-9F2C-B9C978DB1007> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.d
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This are some  issue with xcode 10.2.1 (archiving or installing release build) .I recently faced the same issue. Try  to archive or upload build using xcode 10.1 .It will solve your problem.

Comment: You know what, you're right. The current store build I have was built from XCode 10.1. XCode 10.2 and 10.2.1 builds are being rejected. If this is the case shouldn't this be common knowledge to the App reviewer? They provide the crash logs, but do you see anything in the above log that would help a developer find the issue and fix it?

Comment: You sir are the man! The crash logs offer no help on this issue so you're totally in the dark. This was 100% an issue with archiving the build from Xcode 10.2 or 10.2.1. Apple surly knows of this issue. The app reviewer should have mentioned this but the responses were simply "App Crashed on Launch. Here are the crash logs. Fix the issue and resubmit". And it's entirely a regression in Xcode. I've been going back and forth on this for days... I just submitted with Xcode 10.1 and it was approved. Unreal. Thanks again!

Comment: @mejim707 I faced the same issue, I raised the ticket to Apple support for the same.didn't receive any update yet.